# Will inserting multiple rows in 'Notifications' table slow down the query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a website with a 'following' concept. Whenever a user uploads a picture or a video, I query the 'following' table to get everyone who follows the uploader, and then using a loop to append their name to an INSERT query and then executing it on the 'notifications' table, like is suggested here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp.

Trouble is, if the person has, say, 2000 followers, this can result in a massive query, along with 2000 entries in the 'notifications' table. Is this an optimal algorithm, or is there a better way to do this? How do bigger websites like Quora handle this?

Comment: Bigger websites tend to use "Message Queues" to handle these on the backend. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JeremyHarris All I have tried is the method I explained in the question. Are message queries really more efficient? Could you help me out by providing a tutorial or something? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not "message queries"....Message Queues. Think of them like a box on your server or in the cloud somewhere that you can throw things into in real time quickly, then come back and process them in order with something like a PHP script running every 10 minutes with CRON. https://www.sitepoint.com/message-queues-comparing-beanstalkd-ironmq-amazon-sqs/

Comment: You should not need to build some long insert based on data from the database, that is what the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax is for; you could even do it in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with how bigger websites like Quora handle this, but if I were in your shoes I would do a couple things:

- Use a NoSQL database to store the `notifications`. This is faster than running tons of MySQL queries all the time (but usually aren't acidic).
- Run the `notification` queries in a CronJob or other queueing system so it doesn't make the end-user wait for the queries to run before loading the next page.

Hope this helps.